# How to run a function on scroll start

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll

I have seen many answers for this type of question. But nothing works for me. How can I start my function if the user start scrolling. I am using something like this.

```
$(window).scroll(check);
check();
```

But this works when user scrolls to down. I want to start my function soon when user start scrolling. There is something like **scrollstart** in jQuery. How to do that? In jQuery

Comment: Here check is my function

Answer (score 2):

The proper form is to put the function call in the jQuery method's callback -

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     check();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/mULEm/

Keep in mind that this will continue to call the function as you scroll.